# Looking for literature that gives a systematic presentation of geometric and topological features of trees

Tags: botany, homework, trees, morphology

**Introduction**

I am a software engineer specializing in procedural generation of 3D models, and currently I'm building a generator for 3D models of trees, founded on the theoretical work of **Aristid Lindenmayer**. Having successfully constructed the system framework, my next endeavor is to incorporate distinct tree species models for generation.

**Challenge at Hand**

Despite my proficiency in software development, I lack the comprehensive biological knowledge essential to accurately deduce tree morphologies from visual references. I feel like my unfamiliarity with botanical terminology and key morphological features of trees prevents me from "seeing" the important parts of tree morphology.

**Request for Assistance**

To achieve a high degree of biological accuracy in my models, I seek recommendations for literature detailing the fundamental principles governing visible tree features. This includes the distribution of branches and sub-branches, inherent regularities and anomalies of certain features, variations in tree girth across species, potential branch count and orientations specific to species, among other external features. It would be great if the resource is supplemented with illustrative diagrams. Currently, my primary interest lies in modeling Conifers, hence a dedicated section on this category would be nice.I'm not interested in chemical or developmental models. At the moment I'm just interested in the analysis *geometric* (quantitative) and *topological* (qualitative) features of trees.

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Please continue the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this stack and how we work. Please note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) requirement.

Comment: I have a couple of questions about your question - 1) by "principles" do you mean how they form or just the different types of form (leaf arrangements, types etc.)? 2)What do you already know about the above (see homework...). Please also note there are roughly 73,000 tree species and about 600 different class Pinopsida species, so a general answer might not be possible, though going up a couple of divisions from species to family, might be able to generalize at that level. There will also be well studied species (timber ones) like *Pinus radiata* you should look into.

Comment: Not meaning to spam you at all... but a nice bit of [nominative determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism) in Aristrid's name - Linden is a type of tree; *Tilia* genus, and Meyer means "farmer" so (Linden) tree farmer.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks for the feedback sir! I added the ```homework``` tag since my question is of that kind -- it addresses a kind of basic biology concept that is trivial to professionals. Feel free to edit my question the way you see it fit. I'm new to the stack so please forgive is the question doesn't belong here.

Comment: @bob1 As for the clarifications: 1) currently I'm not interested in developmental models, so formation processes are of a lesser interest to me. References on the topic are welcome though, as I will be interested in learning about it at a future time. 2) As I mentioned, my background in biology is thin. Most of the things I know about the topic are things from computer science literature and papers. They mostly don't do a comprehensive analysis of tree features. They do a kind of pragmatical analysis that helps the models "looks good" without really diving deep into biological side of things.

Comment: @bob1 What I would like is some sort of a starting point literature for me to get familiar with the biology side of this multifaceted coin. An example of the type of "laws" I'm looking for is say how the cross section area of the branches changes at branching points. One other example would be what types of branchings are most likely to be found on tree species. By "types of branching" I mean qualitatively different types. Conifer trees usually branch away from one single main pole that doesn't change direction, while say apple tree's "main" branch changes the direction. That type of things.

Comment: @bob1 I'm aware that I can find this type of things sporadically on blogs etc., but I would like to have a comprehensive book(s) that goes through this topic in a systematic fashion, because blogs are usually focused on one topic and I have to _know about the topic in the first place_ in order to find it. But since I'm a total beginner in learning biology and botany I don't even know the types of questions I can ask, so a list of books that I can study would be a gold mine for me. Also thanks for the bit of trivia you posted, it's always fun to find out about such unexpected connections.

Comment: Those sorts of information might be tricky to find, if they have been studied at all. I would start looking for forestry information on *Pinus radiata*, though there they are more interested in having a straight trunk and aren't interested in the branches so much, but cross-section of the trunk at branching might have been looked at.